# Getting a 403 while connecting local bot to local WebChat client (works with Emulator though)

Tags: botframework, ngrok, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I am trying to connect my local webchat client to my local bot but it's throwing a 403. I tried adding `localhost:3000` (port for my webchat) as a trusted origin but it still doesn't help. However, it works just fine if I use the emulator or postman (the token generation part to connect via Directline)

Here's everything I did:

- Started my local bot and used ngrok to map it to an internet address.
- Changed the messaging endpoint to `https://xxxxx.ngrok.io/api/messages`
- Configured a directline channel, took the secret key and used it in my react webchat client (running on port 3000) to establish directline connection using `createDirectLine` from `botframework-webchat` and passing a token. I am hitting to this API in this format:

```
POST https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate
Authorization: Bearer SECRET
```

After this point the console throws an error 403 and doesn't allow me to proceed further. However, I am able to generate the token through postman and the same ngrok URL works great with the bot framework emulator.

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong. I spent a good part of my day researching on getting till this step and would really appreciate an input from the experts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> works great with the bot framework emulator

When you are testing with Emulator, are you using a username/password, or is it blank? Make sure the `MicrosoftAppID` and `MicrosoftAppPassword` are configured in the bot when running locally and you are using NGROK to go through channels.

Comment: I am not using any username or password. It's blank @dana-v

Comment: Ok, when you are testing through Azure (even when pointing back down to your local running bot through ngrok), you must supply App ID and Password that is configured for the app/bot channels registration.

Comment: I already tried doing that. It gives the same 403 error above like with WebChat. The only way it works is through the emulator with no creds. I read some articles and it says that I need to run offline directline for this to work. Will try that and get back to you if it works.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your problem @NaserMohdBaig? Would be great to know how (in that case) as I'm running into something similar.

Comment: @pgoldweic, I don't remember the configuration steps of it since it was from my previous company but using offline-directline did help me: https://github.com/ryanvolum/offline-directline

The best place to start would be the documentation for the package above and some trial and error. Wish I could help you more. Why don't you give it a shot and let me know if you encounter any errors? Perhaps it will comeback to me if I see any errors ;)

Good luck